# Googlebot connection unique ip

Tags: web-crawler, googlebot

Morning to everyone,

i manage a multilingual (7 languages) website that according from your IP of the user, shows an specific language version.

For this reason, i need to know if the crawlers used by google to index websites for the international versions (for example google.it and google.co.uk) has the same IP (so the crawlers come from the same country, for example USA), or if they have specific IP depending on the international versions (for example: for google.it, google has a googlebot that comes from Italy and for google.co.uk, google has a dedicate connection from the UK).

With this information, we'll be able to make index Googlebot the correct language version of the site, because right now, the crawler seems to have an english spoken country IP, and so seems that the only english version of our site is indexed.

Thank to all you guys in advance for your help,

Josué